# Elasticsearch : Curl does not work

Tags: curl, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I have ES 2.2.0 and i am trying

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200" -d @jnk.json
```

but i get

```
Warning: Couldn't read data from file "jnk.json", this makes an empty POST.
No handler found for uri [/] and method [POST]
```

here are the contents of the file jnk.json

```
PUT junktest 
{
  "mappings": {
    "test": {"properties": {
        "DocumentID": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "Tags":{
            "type" : "string",
          "index" : "not_analyzed"
        },
        "Summary": {
          "type": "string",
          "index" : "not_analyzed"
        },
        "Status": {
          "type": "string",
          "index" : "not_analyzed"
        },
        "Location": {
          "type": "string",
          "index" : "not_analyzed"
        },
        "Error": {
          "type": "string",
          "index" : "not_analyzed"
        },
        "Author": {
          "type": "string",
          "index" : "not_analyzed"
        },
        "Sector": {
          "type": "string",
          "index" : "not_analyzed"
        }
        "Created Date": {
          "type":   "date",
          "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST /junktest/test/
{

             "DocumentID":"555661",
             "Tags":["A","B","C","D"],
             "Summary":"Summary Text",
             "Status":"Review",
             "Location":"HDFS",
             "Error":"None",
             "Author":"Poi KLj",
             "Sector":"Energy",
             "Created Date":"2013-04-23"
}

POST /junktest/test/
{

             "DocumentID":"555662",
             "Tags":["B","C","D"],
             "Summary":"Summary Text",
             "Status":"Review",
             "Location":"HDFS",
             "Error":"None",
             "Author":"Abc Mnb",
             "Sector":"Energy",
             "Created Date":"2013-05-23"
}
```

so i am creating a mapping and then posting a single document. What am i doing wrong?

I get the same result for `-XPUT`

**Edit**

thanks a lot @Bahaaldine Azarmi! there was the missing comma and i was able to create the mapping separately :) but i tried the bulk command as

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/_bulk" --data-binary @post.json
```

as per the api, and it gave me error

```
    {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"json_parse_exception","reason":"Unexpected char
acter (':' (code 58)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 't
rue', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: [B@2f1a62ab; line: 1, column: 27]"}],"typ
e":"json_parse_exception","reason":"Unexpected character (':' (code 58)): expect
ed a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at
 [Source: [B@2f1a62ab; line: 1, column: 27]"},"status":500}
```

here is my post.json

```
{ "index" : { "_index" : "junktest", "_type" : "test"} }
{

             "DocumentID":"555661",
             "Tags":["A","B","C","D"],
             "Summary":"Summary Text",
             "Status":"Review",
             "Location":"HDFS",
             "Error":"None",
             "Author":"Poi KLj",
             "Sector":"Energy",
             "Created Date":"2013-04-23"
}
```

is there something wrong with my syntax? which `:` character is out of place?

**Fixed**

Line breaks are not allowed in bulk api as these are treated as delimiters. So the correct format of file is

```
{"index":{"_index":"junktest","_type":"test"}}
{"DocumentID":"555661","Tags":["A","B","C","D"],"Summary":"Summary Text","Status":"Review","Location":"HDFS","Error":"None","Author":"Poi KLj","Sector":"Energy","Created Date":"2013-04-23"}
```

the input file **must end with a line break**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well these queries syntaxes need to be copied and pasted in Sense (https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-sense-a-cool-json-aware-interface-to-elasticsearch). With Sense, you will be able to run every query sequentially.

If you want to use curl, then split the work in two calls:

Use the following to create your mapping

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/junktest" -d @mapping.json
```

By the way, your mapping is missing a comma here

```
},
"Created Date": {
```

Then make a second call that use the bulk API to index your Json objects in a single query, example here:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html