# elasticsearch query_parse_exception Unexpected character (':' (code 58)): was expecting comma to separate ARRAY entries\n

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm a novice and have installed es2.3.1 on my server.But when I read The Definitive Guide on the website, I found an example which I got an error on my server. [Here](http://Unexpected%20character%20(':'%20(code%2058)):%20was%20expecting%20comma%20to%20separate%20ARRAY%20entries%5Cn%20at%20[Source:%20[B@29d143;%20line:%201,%20column:%2035]) is the link and the error is as follows:

```
{
"error" : {
"root_cause" : [ {
  "type" : "query_parsing_exception",
  "reason" : "Failed to parse",
  "index" : "megacorp"
} ],
"type" : "search_phase_execution_exception",
"reason" : "all shards failed",
"phase" : "query",
"grouped" : true,
"failed_shards" : [ {
  "shard" : 0,
  "index" : "megacorp",
  "node" : "yZnpVEOVSl-4Q6fyrU-1EQ",
  "reason" : {
    "type" : "query_parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "Failed to parse",
    "index" : "megacorp",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "json_parse_exception",
      "reason" : "Unexpected character (':' (code 58)): was expecting comma to separate ARRAY entries\n at [Source: [B@29d143; line: 1, column: 35]"
    }
```

I've searched this question and found some similar question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35181736/elasticsearch-curl-does-not-work), but unfortunately it doesn't work. What makes me confused is that though I copied the book's code and still got an error. Can anyone help me with that? Thanks very much!

Comment: Your link is not working. What is the query that you are running?

Comment: ... I'm so sorry about that. Thanks.  [Here is the link](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_more_complicated_searches.html/)  @alpert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there is a typo in example. You need to change square brackets with curly brackets:

```
GET /megacorp/employee/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "match" : {
                    "last_name" : "smith" 
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "range" : {
                    "age" : { "gt" : 30 } 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Got it. I've tried your method and it worked! Thanks again!